# Redis NOAUTH authentication required error kubernatives

Tags: kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm

We are getting error NOAUTH Authentication required when deploying in kubernatives cluster.
we need to remove the password which has set automatically. but we don't know from where to change as no config file is there.

Comment: feel free to post a new question or edit this with details like common details, no one will be aware of how you are configuring the Redis, using helm or not, or how your config looks like. so please feel free to edit or post new questions with proper descriptions, details, and config file that makes little sense.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.